# Haskell Filter (3-tuple) list with the list itself

Tags: haskell

I'm still new to Haskell and am trying some things. I've got a list full of Pythagorean triples. Now I want to remove all identical triples. For example (6,8,10) is in a way identical to (3,4,5). So I wrote a function which checks whether two 3-tuples are identical or not, if it's identical it returns `True`, if not `False`. But now I have a list of 3-tuples (among which are identical triplets) and I want to filter out all the identical (3-tuples). I've been searching for identical problems on StackOverflow, but sadly couldn't find anything that I could use.

My current code is below. (Don't mind efficiency, because I'm sure I'm doing it very inefficient at the moment.)

Generating the list of triples:

```
pyth :: Int -> [(Int, Int, Int)]
pyth i = [(a, b, c) | a <- [1..i], b <- [1..a], c <- [1..i], (a^2) + (b^2) == (c^2)]
```

Some functions to help work with 3-tuples:

```
first :: (Int, Int, Int) -> Int
first (a,_,_) = a

second :: (Int, Int, Int) -> Int
second (_,a,_) = a

third :: (Int, Int, Int) -> Int
third (_,_,a) = a
```

The function which checks if two triples are identical or not:

```
    doubleCheck :: (Int, Int, Int) -> (Int, Int, Int) -> Bool
    doubleCheck a b
     | (((first b) `div` (first a)) == ((second b) `div` (second a))) &&
      ((first b) `mod` (first a) == 0) && 
      ((second b) `mod` (second a) == 0) = True
     |  otherwise = False
```

Now with the things I heard and read about Haskell and the power of higher order functions I suppose the solution would be like two lines of code or something. But I'm stuck with this for like a day and can't figure out how to solve this problem.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: See [`Data.List.nub`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:nub) and [`nubBy`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:nubBy) for removing duplicates

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can suggest a few simplifications.

First, boolean are ordinary values. They do not have to be relegated to `if` guards, or `| ...` guards. In particular,

```
f x | condition = True
    | otherwise = False
```

can be simplified to

```
f x = condition
```

In your specific case:

```
doubleCheck :: (Int, Int, Int) -> (Int, Int, Int) -> Bool
doubleCheck a b = 
   (((first b) `div` (first a)) == ((second b) `div` (second a))) 
   && ((first b) `mod` (first a) == 0)
   && ((second b) `mod` (second a) == 0)
```

Second, let's remove some redundant parentheses, there's too much noise there.

```
doubleCheck :: (Int, Int, Int) -> (Int, Int, Int) -> Bool
doubleCheck a b = 
   (first b `div` first a) == (second b `div` second a) 
   && (first b `mod` first) == 0
   && (second b `mod` second a) == 0
```

Actually, we could remove all the parentheses in the last three lines, but let's leave some of those.

Third, you helper functions do not help at all. Forget about such accessors, and exploit pattern matching when you need it.

```
doubleCheck :: (Int, Int, Int) -> (Int, Int, Int) -> Bool
doubleCheck (a1,a2,a3) (b1,b2,b3) = 
   (b1 `div` a1) == (b2 `div` a2) 
   && (b1 `mod` a1) == 0
   && (b2 `mod` a2) == 0
```

By the way, the above now looks wrong, since you did not handle `a3,b3` at all. You should fix that, I think?

Anyway, to filter a list and keep only the first copy of each triple, we can use `Data.List.nubBy`

```
nubBy doubleCheck myListOfTriples
```

This has O(n^2) complexity, which is not that great, but it should do. At the moment I can't find a better complexity solution for this specific problem.

Perhaps, one could reduce each triple by diving each component by the gcd of the triple. After this normalization process, our equivalence is plain identity. Hence we can sort in O(n log n) and then remove duplicates in O(n).

Comment: Thanks, the solution was even shorter than I thought. And thanks for pointing out and explaining which improvements I can make to my code. I don't really understand the last part, but that's probably because my math skills aren't that respectable :)

Comment: "By the way, the above now looks wrong, since you did not handle a3,b3 at all. You should fix that, I think?"


I thought that if you check the first two parameters of both tuples you automatically check the third. But now I'm not sure. I'm going to look into that, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Sorry for another comment, but I thought about it and `b1 div a1 == b2 div a2` takes care of that. So I don't have to check a3 and b3

Comment: @Snake If they are indeed Pythagorean triples, that looks correct, you only have to check two. For some reason, I thought you wanted to check that on arbitrary triples.

Comment: Just as an additional stylistic note, if you know you don't need to use `a3` and `b3`, you can signify this directly by writing it as `doubleCheck (a1, a2, _) (b1, b2, _)`. This really only silences `-fwarn-unused-binds`, so it's not hugely important, just something to keep in mind as you write more functions.